# What does `hl` stand for?

Tags: google-api, abbreviation

Various Google API endpoints and webpages use a `hl=<language code>` parameter in the query string to set the language.
Example

> hl=en

or

> hl=no

What does `hl` stand for?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It stands for "host language", according to [this page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#WebSearch_Query_Parameter_Definitions)

Comment: I thought it stands for human language :-)

Answer (score 5):

It is not intuitively obvious, but `hl` designates the web interface language per [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-language-codes).

Comment: But there's no "h" in "interface".

Comment: Nonetheless, per the document, it designates the web interface language. And per your answer, it apparently used to (and maybe still does) stand for "host language", which, I suppose, is the web interface language.

Comment: "stands for" == "is an abbreviation for"