# Google search - Language from URL

Tags: url, google-search

Is it possible to choose in which language Google Search is going to present results? I would like to let users in my application search the web, but with a slightly adjusted browser, how could I specify the language that Google Search uses there?

The standard URL is `www.google.com`, but this always searches English for me.

Comment: See also [What does hl stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271747/what-does-hl-stand-for) and [superuser.com: How can I force my browser to search Google in English?](https://superuser.com/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english) and even better [Web Applications Stack Exchange: How to restrict a Google search to results of a specific language?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/how-to-restrict-a-google-search-to-results-of-a-specific-language)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use `hl={lang}` as part of the query string.  For example `https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=waffles` searches for 'waffles' in the German language (Deutsch = de).

I found this by performing a Google search, clicking "Settings -> Languages", changing to a different language and noting the abbreviation used in the `hl={lang}` portion of the query string.

You should be able to use this method to determine other language identifiers for the `hl={lang}` section.

Comment: Very useful for a Tor user like me, as Google's subdomains (e.g. trends) set language based on IP-based geolocation & there seems no easy way to stop it

Answer (score 5):

To set the Google **interface** language, use `&hl=XX`.

To set the preferred language of the **search results**, use `&lr=lang_XX`.

For example, to have the Google interface in Italian, but have search results offer mostly German pages, use

```
&hl=it&lr=lang_de
```